# How to prefill email address in FirebaseUI FUIEmailAuth signup for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebaseUI for doing an iOS app authentication.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

I want to use two different flows for signin and signup

I am currently using "email" parameter in signIn method for pre-fill the email address

```
FUIEmailAuth.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController, email: "default@email.zzz")
```

This method runs when I push the signIn button

```
func signin() {
          
    self.authUI.tosurl = nil
    self.authUI.privacyPolicyURL = nil
    
    if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController {
        let providerFUIEmailAuth = FUIEmailAuth(authAuthUI: self.authUI, signInMethod: EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod, forceSameDevice: false, allowNewEmailAccounts: false, requireDisplayName: false, actionCodeSetting: ActionCodeSettings())
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            providerFUIEmailAuth
        ]
        self.authUI.providers = providers
        providerFUIEmailAuth.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController, email: defaultEmail)
    }
    
}
```

and this one runs when I push the signUp button

```
func signup() {

     self.authUI.tosurl = URL(string: "https://uptivo.fit/privacy-and-terms-of-use/")!
     self.authUI.privacyPolicyURL = URL(string: "https://uptivo.fit/privacy-and-terms-of-use/")!
     
     if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController {
         let providerFUIEmailAuth = FUIEmailAuth(authAuthUI: self.authUI, signInMethod: EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod, forceSameDevice: false, allowNewEmailAccounts: true, requireDisplayName: false, actionCodeSetting: ActionCodeSettings())
         let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
             providerFUIEmailAuth
         ]
         self.authUI.providers = providers
         providerFUIEmailAuth.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController, email: defaultEmail)
     }
}
```

The email address is properly prefilled for signIn

[image]

but not for signUp

[image]

Is it a bug?
Is there any other way to pre-fill the signup email address?

Looking for help, I've opened a specific issue in FirebaseUI project

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/1145